# Mega menu conversion to mobile dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have applied a mega menu in one of my websites i.e. http://www.risenotes.com but when I try to convert it into a single and shortened menu for mobile view, it does not work. I succeeded initially for mobile view but only either of the two views work. Can anyone guide about any javascript code for displaying mega menu as regular mobile menu.

I tried using the below javascript but it succeeded me in my work on mobile version only while regular website version failed. Also, please that I have installed a mobile menu on http://www.risequotes.com which works perfect. That website is built in wordpress while my mega menu site is a php based website. Is there a way to apply my wordpress menu style to my php site? I mean some script.

I have tried below script which worked for conversion into mobile menu (including icons) but I need a bit more sophisticated version.

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">

function responsiveMobileMenu() { 
  $('.rmm').each(function() {
   
   
   
   $(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list'); // mark main menu list
   
   
   var $style = $(this).attr('data-menu-style'); // get menu style
    if ( typeof $style == 'undefined' ||  $style == false )
     {
      $(this).addClass('graphite'); // set graphite style if style is not defined
     }
    else {
      $(this).addClass($style);
     }
     
     
   /*  width of menu list (non-toggled) */
   
   var $width = 0;
    $(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
     $width += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    
   // if modern browser
   
   if ($.support.leadingWhitespace) {
    $(this).css('max-width' , $width*1.05+'px');
   }
   // 
   else {
    $(this).css('width' , $width*1.05+'px');
   }
  
   });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

 /*  build toggled dropdown menu list */
 
 $('.rmm').each(function() { 
    var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
    if ( menutitle == "" ) {
     menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
     menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    var $menulist = $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
    var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
    $(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

  });
}

function adaptMenu() {
 
 /*  toggle menu on resize */
 
 $('.rmm').each(function() {
   var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
   $width = $width.replace('px', ''); 
   if ( $(this).parent().width() < $width*1.05 ) {
    $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
    $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
   }
   else {
    $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
    $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
   }
  });
  
}

$(function() {

  responsiveMobileMenu();
  getMobileMenu();
  adaptMenu();
  
  /* slide down mobile menu on click */
  
  $('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
   if ( $(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
     $(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
     $(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
   }
   else {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
     $(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
   }
  
 }); 

});
 /*  hide mobile menu on resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
  adaptMenu();
});

</script>
```

My current use of CSS hides the menu for mobile view and displays only parent Lists.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript, can you use CSS media queries?

```
/* Mobile styling goes here */

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    /* Desktop styling overrides go here */
}
```

Here's an example (I'm not going to copy what you did, but you should get the gist of it) http://jsfiddle.net/1gw19yqg/